# Can't find vcf file on SDCard Android Emulator

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

Here is my code to export contacts to VCF file on SDcard. But i can't find vcf on SDCard.
Help me find that. Thanks in advance

Code to get VCF file:

```
public static void getVCF() 

{

 final String vfile = "POContactsRestore.vcf";

 Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

 phones.moveToFirst();
   for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
   {
      String lookupKey =  phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
     Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
     try 
     {
         fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
         FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
         byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
         fis.read(buf);
         String VCard = new String(buf);
         String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
         FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
                    mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());           
         phones.moveToNext();                           
         Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);
     } 
     catch (Exception e1) 
     {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e1.printStackTrace();
     }

 }
}
```

Manifest
// permisson

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + file.separator + vfile;
```

Comment: can you verify (via debug) that the "path" is pointing where you want it?? also, where do you call `mFileOutputStream.close()`?

Comment: i'm beggin in android, could you show me how to verify "path" via logcat or debug?

Comment: i assume you are using Eclipse. if so you can right-click on the beginning of a line and "set breakpoint". to start the app in DEBUG mode, simply hit F11. the debugger should stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: pls "up vote" my answer if it helped you. good luck on your future projects!

Comment: break the function down into the 2 separate things you are trying to accomplish (READing a file and WRITEing a file). debug them separately, when they both work, recombine them and viola! it'll work.

Comment: Thanks @David M, i found the vcf file on real device